# inserting only unique values on click of submit button

Tags: java, database, jakarta-ee, servlets

The scenario is such that i am accepting a unicode string from user on webpage and on click of the submit button the control moves to the next page where the complete logic of processing  the string is written using a bean class at the same time i m inserting the string into the database by giving call to function of DAO class from inside bean class so as to maintain the log.

the problem is that when user refreshes the result page the bean class is getting called again and again and hence the same string is getting inserted into the database by the same user several times.

what should i do such that string inserted by the same user gets inserted into database only when user presses the submit button not while refreshing the result page.
or should i maintain the cookies with string as values from the user and check it when page gets loaded.

i am trying to maintain cookies at client side for the string that was previously entered by the user and check it accordingly

```
private void fnSetCookieValues(HttpServletRequest request,
                               HttpServletResponse response) {          
  Cookie[] cookies=request.getCookies();
  for (int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {                    
    System.out.println("" + cookies.length + "Name" + cookies[i].getName());
    if(cookies[i].getName().equals("DNString")) {   
      System.out.println("Inside if:: " + cookies[i].getValue() +
                         "" + cookies.length);
      cookies[i].setValue(request.getParameter("txtString"));
    } else {
      Cookie ck = new Cookie("DNString", ";");
      response.addCookie(ck);
}           
  }
}
```

This piece of code is written in servlet which gets called on submit button click
but each processing of this servlet displays **1NameJSESSIONID** it is not showing the cookie DNString

Can anybody figure out the mistake i am doing?

Answer (score 0):

you are looking into a way to prevent double-submits?
There are a couple of approaches, depending on your security needs and the frameworks you are using:

1. Java Script
2. Tokens
3. Synchronization

Google around a bit. There are many many solutions out there.

Thanks,
M

Answer (score 0):

It is not good approach to check whether data is already entered or not.
So, One of the easy solution to this problem is to use HTTP redirect after the form submission from your `servlet`.Let say to `success.jsp`. Hence the form is not submitted again.

You can also reset your form once you get response.

[For More check here](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=582)